# how to crop raster based on SpatialPolygons in R

Tags: r, crop, r-raster, r-sp

I would like to crop a raster based on `SpatialPolygons` object. I know that we can use `crop` function in `raster` package,

```
raster::crop(rasterFile, SpatialPolygonsObject)
```

but this function is based on the `extent` of `SpatialPolygons` object, so the cropped result is rectangle. However, in some case, `SpatialPolygons` object is not rectangle, how to deal these situations?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `raster::mask`.  Here's a reproducible example:

```
library(raster)
r = raster(vals = rnorm(400), nrows=20, ncols=20, ext= extent(c(0, 20, 0, 20)))
p = Polygon(matrix(5, 5, 15, 12, 7, 16, 3, 10), ncol=2, byrow = T))
p = SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(p), "p")))

plot(r)
lines(p)
```

[image]

```
r2 = mask(r,p)
plot(r2)
```

[image]

If you also need to clip the extent of the raster to remove empty rows and columns around the mask, then you can either use `crop` before applying `mask`, or you can use `trim(r2, values = NA)` afterwards.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  But how to remove these cells that not included in the mask?

Comment: But you can do `crop` before `mask` to eliminate as many cells as possible

Comment: or you use the trim function (from the raster package) to remove outer rows and columns with NA values: `trim(r2, values = NA)`