# I have problems to clip a raster from a polygon in R

Tags: r, geospatial, raster, shapefile

I'm trying to clip a raster file using a polygon as a base. However I have the same error. I provided a example below:

I'm trying to clip a raster file using a polygon as a base. However I have the same error. I provided a example below:

First, I define the polygon.

Here is the polygon

```
library(maptools)
data("wrld_simpl")
cl<-subset(wrld_simpl, NAME=="Chile") 
plot(cl)
```

Then I set the raster file

```
library(geodata)
foot_p<-footprint(year = 2009, path = "data/")
plot(foot_p)
```

I tried to clip the raster with crop function

```
foot.cl<-crop(foot_p, cl)
```

However, its seem to only clip the extent of it, and I need to clip the raster inside the polygon borders. I was tried using mask function, but I hace the error

```
foot.cl2<-mask(foot.cl, cl)
```

but I have the error

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘mask’ for signature ‘"SpatialPolygonsDataFrame", "SpatRaster"’
```

I think could be the CRS between data

```
>foot.cl
class       : SpatialPolygonsDataFrame 
features    : 1 
extent      : -109.4492, -66.42056, -55.9175, -17.50528  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs         : +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +no_defs 
variables   : 11
names       : FIPS, ISO2, ISO3,  UN,  NAME,  AREA,  POP2005, REGION, SUBREGION,     LON,     LAT 
value       :   CI,   CL,  CHL, 152, Chile, 74880, 16295102,     19,         5, -69.433, -23.389 
> foot.cl
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 4609, 5164, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 0.008333333, 0.008333333  (x, y)
extent      : -109.45, -66.41667, -55.91667, -17.50833  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
source(s)   : memory
varname     : wildareas-v3-2009-human-footprint_geo 
name        : wildareas-v3-2009-human-footprint 
min value   :                                 0 
max value   :
```

Any thoughts??, thank you every one

R.

Comment: Maybe have a look at <https://stackoverflow.com/q/41529731/1100107>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get this error

> unable to find an inherited method for function ‘mask’ for signature
> ‘"SpatialPolygonsDataFrame", "SpatRaster"’

Because there is a `mask` method for Raster* and SpatialPolygons* objects, but not for SpatRaster and SpatialPolygons. See `?mask` It is best to move away from the old raster and sp packages, and especially maptools as this package is not on CRAN anymore.

You can do

```
library(geodata)
library(terra)
foot_p <- geodata::footprint(year = 2009, path = "data/")
chl <- geodata::gadm("Chile", level=1, path="data/")

foot.cl <- crop(foot_p, chl, mask=TRUE)
plot(foot.cl)
```

But apporach should also work if you do

```
foot.cl2 <- mask(foot.cl, vect(cl))
```

Answer (score 0):

The error suggests the `maptools` data are not in a format that `crop()` recognises. The CRS of both files are the same, just written differently. Further, the `maptools` package was retired October 2023 so here is a working solution using a polygon of Chile using `map_data()` from `ggplot2`. I used `filter()` to remove Rapanui/Isla de Pascua and Galápagos to keep the file small. You can include them if needed my removing the line `filter(!group %in% c(415:416)) %>%`.

```
library(sf) # For simple feature spatial objects
library(terra) # For raster objects
library(tidyterra) # For plotting terra objects in ggplot2
library(dplyr) # For data wrangling/pipes e.g. %>%
library(geodata) # For footprint data
library(ggplot2) # For plotting and map_data()

# Create sf of Chile
cl <- map_data("world") %>%
  filter(region == "Chile") %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("long","lat")) %>%
  group_by(region, group) %>%
  summarise(geometry = st_combine(geometry), .groups = "drop") %>% 
  st_cast("POLYGON") %>%
  filter(!group %in% c(415:416)) %>% # Removes two islands far away from mainland
  st_set_crs(4326) %>%
  st_as_sf() %>%
  ungroup()

# Get raster data
foot_p <- footprint(year = 2009, path = "data/")

# Crop raster and set cells outside cl to NA
foot.cl <- crop(foot_p, cl, mask = TRUE)

# Plot
ggplot() +
  geom_raster(data = foot.cl,
              aes(x = x, y = y, 
                  fill = `wildareas-v3-2009-human-footprint`))
```

[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid ggplot, you can also use the `raster` package and transform 'foot_p' from SpatRaster to RasterLayer:

```
library(geodata)
library(raster)
foot_p<- raster(footprint(year = 2009, path = "data/"))
```

Then, you can use `mask` like you tried it before:

```
foot.cl <- crop(foot_p,cl)
foot.cl2 <- mask(foot.cl, cl) 

plot(foot.cl2)
```

[image]