Mask and Crop functions in Terra R
When the raster package was still active, I would usually have to do the following to crop the rasterlayer to an irregular polygon (with some functions updated for terra). I am wondering there is a faster/more efficient way to do this same thing?:
kml <- vect("pathtokml.kml")
r <- rast("pathtoraster.tif")

crp <- mask(r, project(kml, r)) #fix for different CRS's
crp2 <- crop(crp, ext(kml))
plot(crp2)


For some performance gain try cropping first and and then mask.  Or jus set mask = TRUE in crop() - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77998525/i-have-problems-to-clip-a-raster-from-a-polygon-in-r

It is more efficient to first crop and then mask, and with terra you can do this in one step.
x <- crop(r, project(kml, r), mask=TRUE)


Great, thanks Robert! We are working on slowly changing over from raster to terra.
